# modify label of relationship

Tags: neo4j

when you create a relationship with a label on the arrow. how do sometime in the future to change the label without delete the relationship? is possible? 
can You  also modify a set of relationships with the same label, in another label?

edit 
I write this to create new and copy property

```
MATCH (m)-[old:INVIA_DATI]->(n)
WHERE ID(m) = 11 AND ID(n) = 13
CREATE (m)-[new:INVIA2{name:old.name}]->(n)
DELETE old
RETURN m, new, n
```

Now work but if I  have 4 property like name,color,connector , other ?
Thanks for all!

Comment: Typo in my answer, corrected. Change `r.name` to `old.name`. In create statements the values in the parenthesis are used to set property values, you are setting a property called 'name' with the value 'old.name', you could equally have hard coded a new value.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can create a new relationship like this:

```
MATCH (m)-[old:OLD_RELATIONSHIP]->(n)
CREATE (m)-[new:NEW_RELATIONSHIP]->(n)
DELETE old
RETURN m, new, n
```

For your example:

```
MATCH (m)-[old:INVIA_DATI]->(n)
WHERE ID(m) = 97 AND ID(n) = 115
CREATE (m)-[new:INVIA2]->(n)
DELETE old
RETURN m, new, n
```

Explanation:

```
MATCH (m)-[old:INVIA_DATI]->(n)
WHERE ID(m) = 97 AND ID(n) = 115
```

These two lines match your nodes with IDs 97 and 115 respectively where (and only where) an `INVIA_DATI` relationship exists between them. `m` is bound to the node with node ID 97, `n` is bound to the node with ID 115 and `old` is bound to the relationship. You could use any values you like instead of n, m and old.

```
CREATE (m)-[new:INVIA2]->(n)
```

This line creates the new relationship between the bound nodes `m` and `n` with the type `INVIA2` you could additionally set properties here. If you want to prevent duplicates being created you can use `MERGE` instead of create.

```
DELETE old
```

This deletes the old relationship.

```
RETURN m, new, n
```

Return the bound values. You don't have to do that if you don't want to, but it's handy in the console to see what has just happened.

And if you need to set a property you can do:

```
CREATE (m)-[new:INVIA2{propname:old.propname}]->(n)
```

This will set the `propname` relationship property with the value from the original propname property, you can set as many properties as you like in this way.

Comment: I again edited my post . now work but if I have more prop? Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything? Just comma separate them {name:old.name, age:old.age}

Answer (score 1):

We have the concept of both a `Label` and a `Relationship Type` in the labeled property graph data model of Neo4j.

For labels on nodes, the following rules apply:

- `Labels` allow you to group nodes together by a role.
- `Labels` only apply to nodes and a node can have zero or more labels.

For relationships, the following rules apply:

- `Relationship Types` are applied only to relationships.
- A relationship can only have one `Relationship Type`.
- `Relationship Types` cannot be changed on a relationship, you must delete the
  relationship and replace it with a new one with a different type.